# Delete selected keys from Dart Map

Tags: dictionary, dart

What is the Dart idiomatic way to remove selected keys from a Map?
Below I'm using a temporary emptyList to hold String keys.
Is there a cleaner way?

```dart
List<String> emptyList = new List<String>();
_objTable.keys.forEach((String name) { 
  if (_objTable[name].indices.isEmpty) {
    emptyList.add(name);
    print("OBJ: deleting empty object=$name loaded from url=$url");
  } 
});
emptyList.forEach((String name) => _objTable.remove(name));
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```dart
_objTable.keys
  .where((k) => _objTable[k].indices.isEmpty) // filter keys
  .toList() // create a copy to avoid concurrent modifications
  .forEach(_objTable.remove); // remove selected keys
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! I'm unable to understand the portion .forEach(_objTable.remove) though. Is it passing the _objTable.remove function to .forEach() ?

Comment: Here, I pass the function to call for each element in list. Basically, it's like `.forEach((name) => _objTable.remove(name))`.

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to remove nested Maps? For example, a Map like this: `{"id": 123, "name": "XXX", person: {"id": 333, "name": "ZZZZ"}}`. I would like to remove from the Map where the `key = 'id'`.

Comment: Thanks, helped solve a bug I was running into :) simple and effective!

Answer (score 47):

Simply do:

```
_objTable.removeWhere((key, value) => key == "propertyName");
```

It works with nested Maps too.

Comment: Simplest solution, Thanks @andreskiu andreskiu.

Comment: Right to the point! Great solution! 10x!