# Delete key in Json File

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I save data in a Json file. Now I would like to implement the option, to delete data out of the file. I know how to delte the values of a key, but I do not know, how to delete the key (together with the values) out of the Json file.

I tried this:

```
fileContent.remove('key');
```

But that doesn't worked.

This is my code to create, read and write to the Json file:

```
  File jsonFile;
  Directory dir;
  String fileName = "MyFile.json";
  bool fileExists = false;
  Map<String, dynamic> fileContent;

  void createFile(Map<String, dynamic> content, Directory dir, String fileName) {
    print("Creating file!");
    File file = new File(dir.path + "/" + fileName);
    file.createSync();
    fileExists = true;
    file.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(content));
  }

  void writeToFile(String key, dynamic value) { 
    print("Writing to file!");
    Map<String, dynamic> content = {key: value}; 
    if (fileExists) {
      print("File exists");
      Map<String, dynamic> jsonFileContent = json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
      jsonFileContent.addAll(content);
      jsonFile.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(jsonFileContent));
    } else {
      print("File does not exist!");
      createFile(content, dir, fileName);
    }
    this.setState(() => fileContent = json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync()));
    print(fileContent);
  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please share your attempt at deleting the key and show us the issue you are facing. StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: just check if this post works for you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038512/delete-selected-keys-from-dart-map

Comment: I have no clue how to delete the key. I am new to coding & flutter...

Comment: @JoãoSoares I added my attempt based on Sagar's help, but that doesn't worked

Comment: don't deal with it as a json file you need to view it as a text file and you can use normal string manipulation functions

Comment: Adding a sample of your json file would help us understand what you want to do.